# Como puedo mostrar datos de una tabla relacionada en CI4?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

estoy aprendiendo recientemente este framework (Codeigniter 4).
Mi consulta es como mostrar en este caso el nombre de la Categoría y no el ID.

**Model**

```
class ProductModel extends Model{
protected $table;

public function __construct() {

parent::__construct();
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$this->table = $this->db->table('product');
}
public function get_product(){
return $this->table->get()->getResultArray();
}}
```

**Controller**

```
class Product extends Controller{
protected $ProductModel;
protected $request;

public function __construct() {

    $this->ProductModel = new ProductModel();
    $this->request = \Config\Services::request();
}

public function index()
{
    $data['product'] = $this->ProductModel->get_product();
    return view('product/index', $data);
}
}
```

**View**

```
<td><?php echo $data['id'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['category_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['product_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['product_description']; ?></td>
```

Aquí es donde quisiera que en lugar del category_id, mostrar el nombre de la categoría. La tabla product y category si están relacionadas correctamente. El tema es creo en el modelo donde falta la unión. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar esta consulta cambiando los nombre de las columnas que relacionan una con otra

```
$builder = $this->ProductModel->select('*');
 $builder->join('product', 'product.category_id=category.category_id');
 $query   = $builder->get();

return json_encode($query->getResult());
```